# Firestore: Where query (==) on map field

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with shipments in them.

[image]

I want to filter on postalcode which is a part of the 'address_from' map.
Is this possible and are there extra steps required, indexes for example, to make this work?

```
 query.where('address_from.postalcode', '==', shipment_code);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query should just work.  Any single field query should work without creating an index, as all fields are indexed by default.  Queries that require an index will yield and error message telling you that one needs to be created, and provide a link to the console to automatically do that.